# How I can add subtitles in .ass/.srt format to m3u8 file?

Tags: m3u8, subtitle

I have m3u8 file with playlist of movie, but I want to add subtitles in .ass/.src file. I know I can add another playlist of subtitles but I have only one subtitle file. Is it possible?

Comment: HLS does not support ass/srt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out section 4.3.1.1 of this RFC8216 at
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8216#section-4.3.1.1

It defines #EXT-X-MEDIA tag with TYPE attribute. The possible value of TYPE are AUDIO, VIDEO,SUBTITLES, and CLOSED-CAPTIONS.

Also read it thoroughly. It said "If the TYPE is CLOSED-CAPTIONS, the URI attribute MUST NOT be present."